# Redirecting subsite URLs to main site via .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, multisite

I have installed WordPress Multisite on a subdirectory.

Recently I found that my group can work together rather than separately so I decided to migrate from Multisite to single site setup.

Before I take my first step I need to get some answers.

My main site and subsite use `www.` and I have this code in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myysite.com 
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.myysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

to redirect all non-www visits to the www version.

If I modify above code like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myysite.com/bd/$1 
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.myysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

will this code make my subsite's URL become the main site URL? Around 100+ pages were indexed on search engines so I just want to keep already established links from subsite to on main site. Like this:

- subsite: `https://www.myysite.com/bd/post-names/` (bd is my subsite)
- main site: `https://www.myysite.com/post-names/`

Also, subsite's export file imported into main site will there be any attachments error? I mean do I have to manually change those links?

Answer (score 0):

Your condition `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myysite.com/bd/$1` is wrong. You can only test host header using `%{HTTP_HOST}` . The `/bd/$1` is part of `%{REQUEST_URI}` . You need a separate condition to check it.

Try :

```
RewriteEngine on

#/bd/foobar to /foobar
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?myysite\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/bd/(.*)$ 
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.myysite.com/%1 [R=301,L]

#redirect non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myysite\.com$ 
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.myysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion.  one of my friends give me this code `RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^tvhex.com 
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.tvhex.com/$1 [R=301,L]
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^bd/(.*)$ https://www.tvhex.com/$1 [R=301,L]` it seems like working. should i keep it or change with yours? btw i also have this code for adding slash `# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
` should i keep it all ? or is there's a way to merge?